# Proving (a part of) Hoeffding's lemma

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Hoeffding lemma goes like this: *Let $X$ be a scalar variable taking values in an interval $[a,b]$. Then for any $t>0$ $$\mathbb{E} e^{tX}\leq e^{t\mathbb{E} (X)}(1+O(t^2\mathbb{V}(X)\exp(O(t(b-a)))).$$In particular $$\mathbb{E} e^{tX}\leq e^{t\mathbb{E} (X)}\exp(O(t^2(b-a)^2).$$(This version is taken from T. Taos book on Random matrices - it's on pp. 61 Lemma 2.1.2 from the draft from his website)

My question is: How can one get the second inequality from the first ? Tao gives as a hint $ $$\mathbb{V}(X)\leq(b-a)^2$.

Comment: The [draft version on his website](http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/matrix-book.pdf) (Lemma 2.1.2, p.61, 69th page of the pdf) concludes
$\mathbb E e^{tX} \le e^{t\mathbb E X} \exp (O(t^2(b-a)^2))$.  Does that help?

Comment: @StevenTaschuk Yes, that was a typo, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me get rid of the $O(\cdot)$-notation: Tao's proof shows

$$\mathbb{E}e^{tX} \leq e^{t \mathbb{E}X} \bigg( 1+ \frac{t^2}{2} \mathbb{V}X \cdot e^{t (b-a)} \bigg).$$

We consider two cases separately:

- $t \leq \frac{1}{b-a}$: For $t \leq \frac{1}{b-a}$, we have $e^{t (b-a)}\leq e^1 \leq 4$, hence $$\mathbb{E}e^{tX} \leq e^{t \mathbb{E}X} \bigg( 1+ 2t^2 \mathbb{V}X \bigg).$$ As $1+x \leq e^x$ for any $x \geq 0$, we conclude $$\mathbb{E}e^{tX} \leq e^{t \mathbb{E}X} \exp(2 t^2 \mathbb{V}X).$$ Finally, $\mathbb{V}X \leq (b-a)^2$ implies $$\mathbb{E}e^{tX} \leq e^{t \mathbb{E}X} \exp(2 t^2 (b-a)^2).$$
- $t \geq \frac{1}{b-a}$: Obviously, $1 \leq e^{t(b-a)}$. Consequently, we find $$\mathbb{E}e^{tX} \leq e^{t \mathbb{E}X} e^{t(b-a)} \left(1+ \frac{t^2}{2} \mathbb{V}X \right).$$ Using $\mathbb{V}X \leq (b-a)^2$ and $1+\frac{x^2}{2} \leq e^x$, $x \geq 0$, we arrive at $$\mathbb{E}e^{tX} \leq e^{t \mathbb{E}X}e^{2t (b-a)}.$$ As $t (b-a) \geq 1$, the monotonicity of $x \mapsto e^x$ entails $$\mathbb{E}e^{tX} \leq e^{t \mathbb{E}X}e^{2t (b-a) \cdot 1} \leq e^{t \mathbb{E}X}e^{2t^2 (b-a)^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you please explain a bit more detailed how you arrive from the inequality involving the supremum to the lat inequality ? I only managed, after playing with it a bit, to get $\tilde{C}+...$ instead of $\tilde{C}\cdot ...$.

Comment: @elle Sorry, there was a typo in it - the constant $C$ doesn't appear in the exponent at all.

Comment: Ok, thanks, now I understand how you got it. But the problem is still there, that in the end I get an additive constant inside the $\exp$ instead of a multiplicative one, which is what I need to show  $$\mathbb{E} e^{tX}\leq e^{t\mathbb{E}(X)}\exp(O(t^2(b-a)^2),$$if I interpreted the big-Oh notation correctly.[...]

Comment: [...] More precisely: I get $\mathbb{E} e^{tX}\leq e^{t\mathbb{E}(X)}\exp(2(t^2(b-a)^2+\log(2C))$ by shuffling the $2C$ inside the $\exp(\cdot)$, which I think amounts to $$\mathbb{E} e^{tX}\leq e^{t\mathbb{E}(X)}\exp(O((t^2(b-a)^2+\log(2C)).$$ But we need  to show  $\mathbb{E}e^{tX}\leq e^{t\mathbb{E}(X)}\exp(\mathscr{C}(t^2(b-a)^2)$, for some positve $\mathscr{C}$ that contains all the other constants from your last formula. The reason is that generally from $f(x)\leq O(g(x)$ I can conclude $f(x)\leq O(g(x)+\mathscr{C})$ for some positive $\mathscr{C}$, but not the other way around.

Comment: (I'm going to award you, out of gratitude, a bounty, if we manage to sort this out completely. :)

Comment: That looks good, but it's too late for me, to look through it now, I'm going to go through it tomorrow.

Comment: @elle No problem, I'm not in a hurry.

Comment: Ok, read it, it's perfect, I started the bounty, but annoyingly have to wait for another 23 hours until I can award it. I have a side question: Do you know what the reason is that Tao keeps different constant explicitly inside the $O(\cdot)$, like $(b-a)$ but hides others ? By definition of the $O$-notation he could as well just hide all the constants...

Comment: @elle Well, because this constant shows the dependence on the distribution of your random variale. Suppose that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent (but not identically distributed) random variables satisfying $a_i \leq |X_i| \leq b_i$ and $\mathbb{E}X_i=0$ (for simplicity). Then we know that $$\mathbb{E}e^{tS_n} \leq e^{2t^2 n \max_{i=1,\ldots,n} |b_i-a_i|^2}.$$ In particular, if $|b_i-a_i|$ is bounded above by some constant $C>0$, then $$\mathbb{E}e^{tS_n} \leq e^{2t^2 C^2 n}.$$ If you simply put *some* constant in the exponent, then it is not obvious that such an uniform estimate holds.

Comment: @elle Thanks for the generous bounty.