# $\mathbb{E}(e^{tS_{n}})\leq e^{Ct^{2}\sigma^{2}}\quad ?$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Let $S_n=X_1 + \cdots+ X_n$ be a sum of independent random variables such that each $X_i$ has mean zero, variance $\sigma_i ^2$ and lies in $[-1,1]$. Denote with $S_n$ the sum of these random variables and with $\sigma$ the sum of all individual variances, i.e. $\sigma^2=\sigma_1^2 + \ldots +\sigma_n^2$ and let $t$ vary between $0$ and $1$.

How can I then prove $$\mathbb{E}(e^{tS_{n}})\leq e^{Ct^{2}\sigma^{2}}\quad ?$$

---

Progress: From $\mathbb{E}(e^{tS_{n}})=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}(e^{tX_{i}})$
one can use Hoeffdings inequality to prove $\mathbb{E}(e^{tX_{i}})\leq e^{C_{i}t^{2}\sigma_{i}^{2}}$,
but from the product one then obtains
$$
\mathbb{E}(e^{tS_{n}})\leq\sum e^{C_{i}t^{2}\sigma_{i}^{2}}\quad\text{instead of}\quad\mathbb{E}(e^{tS_{n}})\leq e^{Ct^{2}\sigma^{2}},
$$
so because $C_{i}$ depends on $i$, one can't pull it in front and sum
the $\sigma_{i}$...

Comment: Didn't you ask this quite recently, and got comments?

Comment: @Did Do you mean this question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/984897/ ...?

Comment: @saz Unfortunately, no, it was a question that I commented, asking for more personal input (as often) and providing specific suggestions to do so. This might have been intolerable to the OP, who preferred to delete the question and repost it?

Comment: @Did I put in some personal input, but couldn't do - probably because I'm too dumb. Sorry for being too dumb...

Comment: Dumbness is offtopic (and invoking it probably a rhetorical trick). Did you or did you not already ask this question in another post that you then deleted?

Comment: @Did I see, thanks.

Comment: @Did Where you a judge in our previous life ? Because in your last comment you sound a bit like one...
(I also wonder, what it was, that you told saz that made you delete your comment.)

Comment: I guess this is the way you found to avoid answering, probably because you know exactly why what you did is contrary to the way the site is supposed to function. (About the innuendo in your parenthesis, note that I deleted no comment (I very rarely do) and feel free to draw the lessons you like about this fact.)

Comment: @Did Well, you imply a lot of bad intention. Good faith doesn't seems to be your strong point. But: Your guess is wrong, although I don't really want to elaborate on how or why (mainly because you didn't answer two comments of mine anf comments stagnated afterwards), since that would entail endless discussions, because with your interrogation-like attitude you'd challenge every second word and by the same attitude I don't really feel like talking much with you.

Comment: In other words: everything I said is true, as you actually admit, but you know better than to follow the way the site is supposed to function, all the rest (evasions, character assassination, imagining nefarious deleted comments) being diversions. Enough is enough.

Comment: @Did Man, you already sound paranoid - I don't even understand what a "character assassination" means. Care to explain ? And although you probably can't bare not to be right every time: no, not everything you said is true - as I said before, assuming bad intention is your starting premise, and that's not very good.

Comment: Is this what they call damage control? Anyway, since the factual content of your comments is rapidly going to zero, I see no reason to continue. All this because you closed a page on which you had received help, only to repost the same question, but refuse to admit it... Bad manners.

Comment: @Did Well, at least we agree on the "no reason to continue" part, though I still wonder about the "character assassination"...Retrospectively I was definitely right saying that this "would entail endless discussions, because [...] you'd challenge every second word" - to which I might add that I also don't view your attitude in a very positive light, since you constantly and harshly imply bad will on my side. So maybe just leave it at reciprocal aversion :)

Comment: @Did Well, at least we agree on the "no reason to continue" part, retrospectively I was definitely right saying that this "would entail endless discussions, because [...] you'd challenge every second word" - to which I might add that I also don't view your attitude in a very positive light, since you constantly and harshly imply bad will on my side. So maybe just leave it at incompatible point of views/reciprocal disliking.

Comment: You agree to not continue... except that you do post new comments, continuing to throw dirt around. Bad manners, definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\mathbb{E}e^{tX_i} \leq e^{C_i t^2 \sigma_i^2} \tag{1}$$

implies

$$\mathbb{E}e^{t S_n} = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}e^{t X_i} \leq \prod_{i=1}^n e^{C_i t^2 \sigma_i^2} = \exp \left( t^2 \sum_{i=1}^n C_i^2 \sigma_i^2 \right).$$

(Please compare this with the inequality you wrote in the last part of your question.) Hoeffdings lemma does not only state that there exists some $C_i$ such that $(1)$ holds, but that the constant $C_i$ equals $\frac{1}{8}$. Consequently,

$$\mathbb{E}e^{tS_n} \leq \exp \left( \frac{t^2}{8}\sigma^2 \right).$$